# Python scraper how to add mysql insert

Tags: python, mysql, xpath

**What is wrong in my code ? I want to add %s to my mysql db.**

```
 titlux = tree.xpath('//*[@id="offer-title"]/h1/text()')
 pretx = tree.xpath('//*[@id="offer-price-stock"]/div[3]/span/@content')

 print "%s," % titlux 
 print "%s," % pretx
 print "\n"
 conn = ..............

 x = conn.cursor()

 try:
    x.execute ("""INSERT INTO produse (titlu, pret) VALUES (%s, %s)""")
    conn.commit()
 except:
    conn.rollback()

 conn.close()
```

Comment: Please: tell us more! And Don't put bold everywhere! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the replacement variables and some quotes in your SQL insert. Change it to:

```
x.execute ("""INSERT INTO produse (titlu, pret) VALUES ("%s", "%s")""" % (titlux[0], pretx[0]))
```

Comment: Thancks, is worcking but give me the resulst like ['1199.99'], cant i remove [' ']?

Comment: That is just Python's output. Your database should show 1199.99. Does it?

Comment: No, is give me the result like: "titlu = [u'Laptop Asus X553MA-SX455B cu procesor Intelxae Celeronxae Dual-Core N2840, 2.16GHz, 4GB, 500GB, Intelxae HD Graphics, Microsoft Windows 8.1, Bing, Black']"

Comment: Your xpath results obviously return lists. I've updated my answer to select the first item in the list. Don't forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

@Alastair has the right answer but if you want to see the query you're using

```
print "INSERT INTO produse (titlu, pret) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (titlux, pretx)
x.execute ("""INSERT INTO produse (titlu, pret) VALUES (%s, %s)""" % (titlux, pretx))
```